# Foreign key relationship in wpdatatables brings in all data from foreign table -- not just data associated with current user

Tags: wordpress

I am having a bug relating to two different settings in WordPress's wpdatatables plugin.  I have a table called "Customers" with columns id, user_id, and name.  Another table is called "Vehicles."  There is a one-to-many relationship between customers and vehicles.  (One customer has many vehicles).  Vehicles uses the id field of customers to relate the two tables.

There is a setting in wpdatatables called "Users see and edit only own data" that when checked, only displays the rows with a user_id matching the currently logged in user.  So, when viewing the "customers" table, a user would only see the rows that have a user_id that matches theirs.

Another setting in wpdatatables allows for implying a foreign key relationship between tables.  In the "Vehicles" table, there is a column called vehicle owner, which corresponds to a customer.  It shows a dropdown menu allowing the logged in user to select from already-existing customers.

The issue is that this dropdown menu displays all customers, not just customers associated with the currently logged in user.  This foreign key relationship and the "user can only see and edit their own data" settings are not cooperating.  Has anybody ever had this problem or have any ideas on how to fix it?  I've already been in contact with the plugin support team and they have been unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in wpDataTables 2.1 release. Now when you use "User can only see and edit their own data" and "Foreign key" features together, filter possible values will be related with the current user.